# error in server when useing telerik:RadAsyncUpload for upload picture in my web site

Tags: asp.net, telerik

This is my code

```
<telerik:RadAsyncUpload runat="server" ID="RadAsyncUpload2" AllowedFileExtensions="jpg,jpeg,png,gif"
    OnFileUploaded="RadAsyncUpload2_FileUploaded" OnClientValidationFailed="validationFailed"
    Skin="Outlook"  InputSize="30" TemporaryFolder=""    
    MultipleFileSelection="Automatic">
    <Localization Cancel="انصراف" Remove="حذف" Select="انتخاب" />
    <FileFilters>
        <telerik:FileFilter Description="*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png; *.gif" Extensions="jpg,jpeg,png,gif"></telerik:FileFilter>
    </FileFilters>

</telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
```

In  my computer this code is run correct full permission folder in host

```
String path = Server.MapPath("~/image/pic_news/");
```

but when uploading picture  in host I cannot upload picture .

What should I do?

Comment: I'd suggest starting here http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload-troubleshooting.html. Make sure the app pool has permissions to write there. Make sure requests are not broken (e.g., by a firewall or authentication mechanism).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please set the AllowedFileExtensions property value as follows

AllowedFileExtensions=".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif,.jpeg"

If this does not work remove the AllowedFileExtensions property and the inner  tag and test again.

Just for test grant full permissions to the everyone user to ensure that this is not a permissions related issue.

Best regards,
Rumen